# Saving XML output from SQL Server to file as UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using `FOR XML PATH` to create an `XML` inside `SQL Server 2014` and I would like to save it as an `UTF-8` file.

Is it possible to do this without using an external tool to convert the file?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was fixed in SQL Server 2014 SP2 and can be done using the BCP tool:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq

To export UTF-8 data to SQL Server, use the BCP utility and run the following command:

```
bcp "query" out "drive:path\file_name" -c -C 65001
```

Using EXECUTE xp_cmdshell around this would probably fix the problem.